# How do you use a css style for Response.Write method?

Tags: c#, css

There are examples in here for applying a .css style for c# controls. But how do you use a .css style for Response.write method?

```
string style = @"<style> table, td, th { border: 1px solid green;  }  th { background-color: green;  color: white;} </style>"
context.Response.Write(style);
```

Comment: What is the problem with the above code?

Comment: It works alright. But naturally I need to expand the style and put in css file for convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that your question is about how to provide CSS classes from css file to Response.Write method. You may have to read the file (you can use System.IO namespace to open and read the file). Since CSS file may have comments as well, you may need to parse it if you want to get rid of it. You can probably explore the CSS parser given [here](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-simple-css-parser) or write your own CSS parser. This answer is based on discussion [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1355949.aspx?Access+CSS+Class+Contents+through+C+code)

Comment: Looks like I can use the solution you pointed. Let me try it and let you know. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Fixed it with `string style = @"<style> " + System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("./MyTableStyle.css")) + "</style>";`